# What's the sane webpack 4 (2018) way to include images in img tags

Tags: webpack, webpack-4

What's the sane webpack 4 (2018) way to include images in `img` tags in my `index.html`?

Considering my folder structure is this:

```
- dist
- src
  - assets
    - images
      - myimage.png
  - index.html
  - index.js
```

In my `index.html` I want to use `<image src="assets/images/myimage.png" />`

In the end I want my `index.html` to be part of the `dist` folder.

**Update**:

I solved it using this `webpack.config.js` but there are still some issues:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        loaders: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]!extract-loader!html-loader',
      },
    ],
  },
};
```

That way I get an `index.html` in my `dist` folder and `<img src="assets/images/myimage.png" />` is replaced by `<img src="2e06734dcef5b5db431246a4a4f626f5.png"/>`.

My `src/index.js` looks like this:

```js
import './index.html'
import './style.scss'
```

Everything would be fine but chaining the loaders as in `loaders: 'file-loader?name=[name].[ext]!extract-loader!html-loader'` [is deprecated](https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/3713#issuecomment-270365920).

So the remaining question is: How to achieve that loader chain without using deprecated features?

Comment: Chain loaders by using an array for the `use` value in the rule. See example in the docs.
https://webpack.js.org/concepts/loaders/#configuration

Answer (score 1):

This `webpack.config.js` solved it for me:

```js
const path = require('path');

module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  entry: './src/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'main.js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.scss$/,
        use: [
          'style-loader',
          'css-loader',
          'sass-loader',
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|svg|jpg|gif)$/,
        use: {
          loader: 'file-loader',
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.html$/,
        use: ['file-loader?name=[name].[ext]', 'extract-loader', 'html-loader'],
      },
    ],
  },
};
```